# TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for &: 'int' and 'float'

Tags: python, if-statement, typeerror

I have just started learning python and during the if-else program, I have stumbled upon the error. the program asks a numeric input from the user and displays the number of digits it has. here is the code:

`

```
num: int = int(input("enter a number : "))
   num = math.fabs(num)
   if (num < 10):
        print("number has 1 digit")
    elif (num >= 10 & num < 100):
        print("number has 2 digits")
    elif (num >= 100 & num < 1000):
        print("number has 3 digits")
    elif (num >= 1000 & num < 10000):
        print("number has 4 digits")
    elif (num >= 10000 & num < 100000):
        print("number has 5 digits")
    elif (num >= 100000 & num < 1000000):
        print("number has 6 digits")
    elif (num >= 1000000 & num < 10000000):
        print("number has 7 digits")
    elif (num >= 10000000 & num < 100000000):
        print("number has 8 digits")
    elif (num >= 100000000 & num < 1000000000):
        print("number has 9 digits")
    else:
        print("the number has 10 digits")`
```

error message : D:\venv\Scripts\python.exe "D:/python projects/conditionalStatements.py"
enter a number : 1000
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "D:/python projects/conditionalStatements.py", line 7, in 
elif (num >= 10 & num < 100):
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for &: 'int' and 'float'

Process finished with exit code 1

Comment: `&` is bitwise-and, which is stronger-binding than comparisons. Use `and`.

Comment: (1) Repeat your tutorial on compound Boolean expressions (likely with the `if` statement): you're trying to do a bit operation on objects of different sizes, for which `&` is not defined.  (2) Check the documentation on operator precedence.

Comment: @tobias_k thank you so much! it is working now

Comment: No conditionals or comparisons needed: `print(f'the number has {math.floor(math.log10(num))+1} digit(s)')`

Answer (score 1):

`&` is bitwise and, which is stronger-binding than comparisons. So this line:

```
elif (num >= 10 & num < 100):
```

is interpreted as this, which is not what you want.

```
elif (num >= (10 & num) < 100):
```

Instead, use the `and` keyword...

```
elif num >= 10 and num < 100:
```

... or comparison chaining.

```
elif 10 <= num < 100:
```

Of course, you could also just replace all those `if/elif` checks using either logarithms or `len` of the numbers's `str` representation:

```
print(f"number has {len(str(num))} digit")
```